# Collapsing data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

- **biblio_contributor_data(cid, lastname, firstname)**
- **biblio_contributor(nid, cid)**

There is several `nid` for each `cid` in the second table. What I would like to do is collapse the data in query in either temporary column or table as in the example.

**biblio_contributor_data**

```
             
+-----+----------+-----------+
| cid | lastname | firstname |
+-----+----------+-----------+
| 1   | john     | grand     |
| 2   | James    | cook      |
| 3   | marco    | palo      |
+-----+----------+-----------+
```

**biblio_contributor**

```
+-----+------+
| nid |  cid |
+-----+------+
| 4   |   1  |
| 4   |   2  |
| 4   |   3  | 
| 5   |   2  |
+-----+------+
```

I would like a query result with the following if possible using SQL statement if possible:

```
+-----+------------------------------------+
| nid | temporary column                   |
+-----+------------------------------------+
| 4   | john grand, James cook, marco palo |
| 5   | James cook                         |
+-----+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONCAT` to combine the `lastname` and `firstname` and use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine the different rows.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.nid,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t2.lastname,' ',t2.firstname)) AS `temporary column`
FROM biblio_contributor t1
JOIN biblio_contributor_data t2
ON t1.cid=t2.cid
GROUP BY t1.nid;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b4ca/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT b1.nid, group_concat(concat(firstname, " ", lastname))
  from biblio_contributor b1, biblio_contributor_data b2 ON b1.cid=b2.cid 
  group by b1.nid
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me:

```
<?php
 $stmt = 'SELECT t2.nid, group_concat(t1.lastname, t1.firstname) FROM `biblio_contributor_data` as t1 INNER JOIN biblio_contributor as t2 GROUP BY t2.nid';
 $res = mysql_query($stmt);
 while($rp = mysql_fecth_array($res)) {
  // YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since until now no one threw in the manual page for GROUP_CONCAT, here it is:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Please have a good read of it, esp. the part

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable